# object reference not set to an instance of an object in check for null

Tags: c#, .net

I'm getting an `object reference not set to an instance of an object` error in the condition of a while loop and I don't know what it's happening. The code is:

```
while (ClassName.StaticDataTable == null || ClassName.StaticDataTable.Rows == null)
```

I tried to make the object names explanatory. I thought `||` was a short circuit operator so that if the first condition was true it wouldn't evaluate the second one and that the error shouldn't be coming from there. Any ideas on what is causing the error?

Comment: Are you positive that the ClassName object itself isn't null?

Comment: Yeah, ClassName is a type and not an object so it can't be null.

Comment: You're getting the error on the while line and not inside the loop right?

Comment: Yeah, it's on the while line and not in the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're getting `null reference` exception on

`while (ClassName.StaticDataTable == null || ClassName.StaticDataTable.Rows == null)`

I think of for example:

`ClassName == null`

So **may be** (just guess) for you would be enough to add one `||` condition more *in front* of others already present, like

`while (ClassName == null || ClassName.StaticDataTable == null || ClassName.StaticDataTable.Rows == null)`

**EDIT**

There could be also a case if `StaticDataTable` property not just returns a value but does something inside it which throws `null reference exception.` Try to dig *into* that property.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That seems to be common suggestion but ClassName is a type and not an object so I can't check that.

Comment: That sounds like it might be the solution.  I am basically doing: return dataset.table["name"]; so I could have a null dataset and get that issue.

Answer (score 0):

Is ClassName the object receiving the 'object reference not set to an instance of an object' or the StaticDataTable?

If it is the ClassName object that is null the attempt to retrieve StaticDataTable would raise that error.

I missed the OR (||) -- the answer below should work. What appears to be happening is the first condition is NOT met when NOT NULL and therefore does NOT short circuit the second condition. While the '&& !=' below meets the '!=' and short circuits the second condition.

If you need the null then try

```
    while (true) {
            if (classname.tbl != null && classname.tbl.object != null){
               break;
            }
             <whatever code you need>
            ...
    } end while
```

This will loop until either are null (both not null)
}

Comment: ClassName is just a class, not an object.  I can't test: if (ClassName == null) because it's a type.